# spawn command not found on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bash, scripts, ssh

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to block SSH login country wise using GeoIP ( From https://www.axllent.org/docs/view/ssh-geoip/),

Please find output of command:

```
$ spawn
spawn: command not found
```

So that I've install *expect* package but still not working:

```
apt-get install expect
expect is already the newest version
```

I want to execute following script:

```
cat /etc/hosts.allow
sshd: ALL: spawn /usr/local/bin/sshfilter.sh %a
```

Have you any idea regarding same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it seem that `spawn` refers to the `spawn` extension to the `hosts.allow` syntax, as described in the `RUNNING OTHER COMMANDS` section of the hosts_options (5) man page (`man hosts_options`):

```
RUNNING OTHER COMMANDS
    aclexec shell_command
           Execute,  in a child process, the specified shell command, after
           performing   the   %<letter>   expansions   described   in   the
           hosts_access(5)  manual  page.   The  command  is  executed with
           stdin, stdout and stderr connected to the null device,  so  that
           it won't mess up the conversation with the client host. Example:

              smtp : ALL : aclexec checkdnsbl %a

           executes,  in  a  background  child  process,  the shell command
           "checkdnsbl %a" after replacing %a by the address of the  remote
           host.

           The  connection  will be allowed or refused depending on whether
           the command returns a true or false exit status.

    spawn shell_command
           Execute, in a child process, the specified shell command,  after
           performing   the   %<letter>   expansions   described   in   the
           hosts_access(5) manual  page.   The  command  is  executed  with
           stdin,  stdout  and stderr connected to the null device, so that
           it won't mess up the conversation with the client host. Example:

              spawn (/usr/sbin/safe_finger -l @%h | /usr/bin/mail root) &

           executes, in a  background  child  process,  the  shell  command
           "safe_finger  -l @%h | mail root" after replacing %h by the name
           or address of the remote host.
```

The fact that `spawn` returns an error when you attempt to run it outside of that context (i.e. as a command in the shell) need not concern you - if you are having issues with proper operation of the GeoIP filtering script that's a separate issue.

---

To demonstrate the successful operation of the hosts.allow `spawn` extension on Ubuntu 14.04 without getting tangled up in GeoIP, you can create a minimal executable /usr/local/bin/sshfilter.sh script that simply logs the IP address and then returns 0, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh

logger "$0: connection from $1"

exit 0
```

Then with the following lines added to the hosts files:

In hosts.deny:

```
sshd: ALL
```

In hosts.allow:

```
sshd: ALL: spawn /usr/local/bin/sshfilter.sh %a
```

Then run

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

in one terminal window and, in another, attempt to log in via SSH:

```
ssh localhost
```

You should see a message in the syslog tail like

```
Jul 25 08:03:59 T61p logger: /usr/local/bin/sshfilter.sh: connection from 127.0.0.1
```

You can confirm that it also works with `aclexec` in place of `spawn`, as suggested in the article you linked. **In fact in this case you should use `aclexec` since `spawn` does not use the exit code of the spawned process to determine whether to allow the connection - which `aclexec` does**.

Comment: _aclexec_ is not work on ubuntu 14.04, So that i'm using spawn but both are not work ! , Is there any way to test both command?

Comment: @RGG can you provide more details about how you determined that it's not working? what did you try - and what happened, exactly?

Comment: see this URL: https://www.axllent.org/docs/view/ssh-geoip/ , In this one of script name "sshfilter.sh" which is allow and deny SSH connection.

Comment: @RGG thanks I already looked at the page you linked - what I'm asking is what part **specifically** isn't working and how you tested it. For example, did you attempt a connection from an allowed country? from a denied country? what messages if any appeared in the log?

Comment: Ok, In script, I've added "allow connection" notification line on If condition then I'm trying to login from other DENY or ALLOW country,  But still able to login from DENY country. If script execute well then It must be show allow/deny message on log file.

Comment: @RGG I've confirmed that both `spawn` and `aclexec` work on my Ubuntu 14.04 system - please see my edited answer for a simple test you can do

Comment: After the reinstall openssh-server, Now I get "DENY and Allow connection" msg on log file but still able to login from DENY Country ? !!! Now I think, spawn issue resolved. Thanks for knowledge sharing.

Comment: Please try changing `spawn` back to `aclexec` for the reason I outlined - I see no evidence that it "doesn't work in Ubuntu" - you shouldn't believe everything you read in random blog comments

Answer (score 7):

`spawn` is `expect` specific command i.e. you need to interpret `spawn` using `expect`.

Most of the time you would use a `expect` script and use `spawn` inside it to start a new process.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh host
expect ....
```

From terminal directly:

```
% expect -c 'spawn whoami'
spawn whoami
```

By default `spawn` echoes the command hence the output in the terminal.